# JPA 2.1 bulk insert takes longer than one without bulk insert

Tags: hibernate, maven, hsqldb, jpa-2.1

I am trying to implement bulk insert in JPA 2.1 using hibernate. when I run my unit test to insert 20000 records, sometimes my bulk insert runs for 26 secs and sometimes for 11 whereas normal insert can run from 7 secs to 34 secs. I am using following techs:

1. Junit 4.9
2. JPA 2.1
3. Hibernate 4.3.5
4. Maven 4

I am using org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence as provider. is it possible to achieve batch insert in this way. should I be taking some other approach. My code is as below

persistance.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <persistence xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence"    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"   xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence              http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_1.xsd" version="2.1">
    <persistence-unit name="batchSettingsUnitTest" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
    <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
    <class>com.repo.MasterDE</class>
    <class>com.repo.ChildDE</class>
    <properties>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class" value="org.hsqldb.jdbcDriver" />
        <property name="hibernate.connection.url" value="jdbc:hsqldb:mem:BatchDB" />
        <property name="hibernate.connection.username" value="sa" />
        <property name="hibernate.connection.password" value="" />
        <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.HSQLDialect" />
        <property name="hibernate.batch.jdbc_size" value="10" />
        <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="false" />
        <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="create-drop" />
        <property name="hibernate.connection.pool_size" value="1" />
        <property name="hibernate.current_session_context_class" value="thread" />
    <property name="hibernate.cache.provider_class" value="org.hibernate.cache.internal.NoCacheProvider" />
    <property name="hibernate.order_inserts" value = "true" />
    </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
    <persistence-unit name="withoutBatchSettingsUnitTest" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
    <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
    <class>com.repo.MasterDE</class>
    <class>com.repo.ChildDE</class>
    <properties>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class" value="org.hsqldb.jdbcDriver" />
        <property name="hibernate.connection.url" value="jdbc:hsqldb:mem:NoBatchDB" />
        <property name="hibernate.connection.username" value="sa" />
        <property name="hibernate.connection.password" value="" />
        <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.HSQLDialect" />
        <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="false" />
        <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="create-drop" />
    </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
    </persistence>
```

My Tests are:

```
    public class TestHsqMemBatchProcessing {
        private int numberOfRows = 20000;
        private EntityManagerGenerator entityManagerGenerator = new EntityManagerGenerator();

@Test

public void testBatchInsert() {
    int previousmastersCount = 0;
    int previouschildsCount = 0;

    EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("batchSettingsUnitTest");
    EntityManager entityManager = EntityManagerFactory.createEntityManager();

    entityManager.setFlushMode(FlushModeType.COMMIT);
    EntityTransaction batchEntityTransaction = entityManager.getTransaction();
    List<masterDE> masters = populateData(3001, 301,numberOfRows, "B");
    batchEntityTransaction.begin();
    try {
        for (int i = 0; i < masters.size(); i++) {

            entityManager.persist(masters.get(i));

            if (i % 10 == 0) {
                entityManager.flush();
                entityManager.clear();
            }
        }

        batchEntityTransaction.commit();

        Query mastersQuery = entityManager
                .createNamedQuery("masterDE.findAll");
        Query childsQuery = entityManager
                .createNamedQuery("childDE.findAll");
        List<masterDE> mastersRetreive = mastersQuery
                .getResultList();
        List<childDE> childsRetreive = childsQuery
                .getResultList();
        assertEquals(
                "Number of MasterDE insert into Hsql must match ",
                numberOfRows + previousmastersCount,
                mastersRetreive.size());
        assertEquals(
                "Number of ChildDE insert into Hsql must match ",
                numberOfRows + previouschildsCount,
                childsRetreive.size());
    } catch (Exception cve) {
        batchEntityTransaction.rollback();
        throw cve;
    } finally {

        if (entityManager.isOpen())
            entityManager.close();
    }

}

@Test
public void testWithoutBatchInsert() {

    int previousmastersCount = 0;
    int previouschildsCount = 0;

    EntityManager entityManager = entityManagerGenerator
            .create("withoutBatchSettingsUnitTest");

    EntityTransaction batchEntityTransaction = entityManager
            .getTransaction();

    List<masterDE> masters = populateData(6001, 601,
            numberOfRows, "W");

    batchEntityTransaction.begin();
    for (int i = 0; i < masters.size(); i++) {
        entityManager.persist(masters.get(i));
    }

    batchEntityTransaction.commit();

    Query mastersQuery = entityManager
            .createNamedQuery("masterDE.findAll");
    Query childsQuery = entityManager
            .createNamedQuery("childDE.findAll");
    List<masterDE> mastersRetreive = mastersQuery
            .getResultList();
    List<childDE> childsRetreive = childsQuery
            .getResultList();

    assertEquals("Number of MasterDE insert into Hsql must match ",
            numberOfRows + previousmastersCount,
            mastersRetreive.size());
    assertEquals("Number of ChildDE insert into Hsql must match ",
            numberOfRows + previouschildsCount,
            childsRetreive.size());
    if (entityManager.isOpen())
        entityManager.close();
}
private List<masterDE> populateData(int masterTrackingId,
        int childTrackingId, int count, String prefix) {
    //do stuff to generate data
    return data;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Interesting. Hibernate has `StatelessSession` for such things. Maybe, JPA has something similar.

Comment: Does it get any faster if you flush at (1%1000 == 0) instead?

Comment: Not really. so I tried running them seperately. weirdly without batch is always faster.

Comment: i checked some comments in other threads and according to them we should not bother batching. I checked using hibernate batching for same data and even now JPA 2.1 without batching runs faster. So i have decided to go without it.